# What could cause this crash in Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I've got a very occassional crash in Realm which I'm unable myself to reproduce.

The top of the backtrace of a crash log is as follows:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x181832d8c __exceptionPreprocess + 228 (NSException.m:166)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1809ec5ec objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:521)
2   Realm                           0x10061e858 invocation function for block in objc_object* (anonymous namespace)::makeBoxedGetter<realm::StringData>(unsigned long) + 304 (RLMObject_Private.hpp:45)
3   My App                          0x1001c239c DetailViewController.getTheTitleOfCaller() + 64 (DetailViewController.swift:1863)
```

The getTheTitleOfCaller() method is as follows.

```
func getTheTitleOfCaller() -> String
    {
        var theTitle: String = ""
        if self.caller?.name != nil
        {
            theTitle = (self.caller?.name)!
        }
        else
        {
            theTitle = "Default title"
        }
        return theTitle
}
```

Has anybody seen this exception for Realm before:
 `invocation function for block in objc_object* (anonymous namespace)::makeBoxedGetter<realm::StringData>`

or knows whats causing this exception?

Comment: I'm struggling with this issue as well. I assume the answer from @David isn't right.... Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @AlexWoe89 unfortunately not.

Comment: hm, damn - I feel like I searched the whole internet, but nothing there. maybe we should start a bounty, what do you think?

Comment: Hey! Any update on this for you both? I'm having it very occasionally too and I'd love to know how to prevent it.

Answer (score 2):

A possible reason for the crash is because you are handling `Optional` unwrapping in an unsafe manner. You shouldn't use nil checking and then force unwrapping since if another thread accesses the same variable between the nil check and force unwrapping, your code will crash. Use optional binding or default values to safely unwrap optionals.

Another possible issue might be the use of `get` in the function name, since Realm is using the Objective-C runtime, so you shouldn't start Swift functions with `get`, because Obj-C might be mistake them for a getter, which might cause the `makeBoxedGetter` to crash.

The `getTitle` function can also be simplified to a single line using default values. I've also changed the function name to make sure the issue isn't caused by its naming.

```
func title() -> String {
    return self.caller?.name ?? "Default title"
}
```

You should also keep in mind that the common coding practice in Swift is to put the opening bracket of functions in the same line as the function declaration, same for `if` statements.

Comment: Thanks, but if that were the problem wouldn't it be  the case that my code that crashed at the force unwrap point and not a crash in the Realm code? Therefore the stack trace would show that it was my code that crashed?

Comment: @Gruntcakes not necessarily, since the property that's force unwrapped is still accessed through the Realm methods. It's hard to tell for sure what's the exact cause of your crash, but I'd definitely say the naming issue is a more probably cause than the force unwrapping. The naming issue being the cause is supported by the stack trace pointing to `makeBoxedGetter`.

Comment: If Obj-C was getting the func mistaken for a getter, wouldn't that cause an issue in my code, not the Realm code? And wouldn't it be repeatable, not occassional? (Actually the method name is longer, I just shorted it for posting, its getTheTitleOfCaller)